# What to use instead of "var" in Asp.Net 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-2.0

I'm craeting 2 dependent drop down menus. So I used the code in this link's solution:
[Dynamically add drop down lists and remember them through postbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256086/dynamically-add-drop-down-lists-and-remember-them-through-postbacks)

But I guess the problem is that var usage belongs to 3.5. So Visual Studio doesn't recognize it. So what can I use instead of var in this line?

```
var items = new List<ListItem>();
```

Comment: This is why `var` should only be used sparingly, in situations where the type of the variable isn't known at compile time. I swear, someone out there is teaching C# programmers to stick `var` in front of *every* variable they declare...

Comment: I must agree it's quite bad practice to use var on known types

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the type of the object being created?

```
List<ListItem> items = new List<ListItem>();
```

Comment: Couldn't recognize "List" this time. Should I add a reference or sth?

Comment: @confeng: Yeah, try adding one to `System.Collections.Generic`.

Comment: And by that I meant the namespace of course, as it isn't really an assembly :)

Answer (score 4):

The `var` keyword was introduced in C# 3.0. It declares an implicitly typed variable where the compiler infers the type of the variable. It is a convenience but if you don't want to use it (or cannot use it in older versions of C#) you can declare the variable using an explicit type instead.

In your case you have to do it like this:

```
List<ListItem> items = new List<ListItem>();
```

You can read more about [implicitly typed local variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: Couldn't recognize "List" this time. Should I add a reference or sth?

Comment: To use the generic `List` class you need a `using System.Collections.Generic` to import the namespace.